# changing color of the points from selected levels of a column

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am trying to plot selected data using shiny and coloring only the points from selected levels in the variable `AD` from dataframe `dataColor`. First, I will check whether I want to color the points. If yes, then I will select the colors using the function `selectedColors` else all the points will be plotted in grey color.

```
  selectedColors <- reactive({
    dataColor[dataColor$AD %in% input$color_levels,'AD']
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

  colour <- "grey"

  if(input$xy=='y'){
    colour = selectedColors()
  }

  plot(selectedData(),col=colour) })
```

I am doing a wrong update of colors in the function `selectedColors`. Any suggestions on how to provide only colors to the selected levels and the rest in grey. Also, the colors should be chosen among others except for grey.

PS: I will try to provide a simulated data soon, if required.

Comment: yes, the data and a full app would be helpful :) My best guess for now is that your problem is that you either have only grey points or no grey points at all?

Comment: No @BigDataScientist. First, i would need to plot all the points in grey and then selected points in different colors.